# Name of operation R uses when multiplying a matrix by a vector

Tags: r, math, matrix, matrix-multiplication, symbolic-math

For m by n matrix **A** and m by 1 vector **b**, what do you call the operation R performs when you run `A*b`? The result is another m by n matrix where each column in A has been multiplied element-wise with the column vector b, but is there a succinct name for this? How would you write this operation using matrix notation? Thanks!

Comment: See: `sweep` and `crossprod`

Comment: The folks at Mathematics answered this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4074677/705836